# Oracle PL/SQL looping through undefined number of groups

Tags: oracle, plsql, logic

I am writing a oracle PL/SQL procedure for the below data set.

> ```
> Column1---Column 2---Column 3
> ID-1      Group1     Item 11
> ID-1      Group1     Item 12
> ID-1      Group1     Item 13
> ID-1      Group2     Item 21
> ID-1      Group2     Item 22
> ID-2      Group3     Item 31
> ID-2      Group3     Item 32
> ID-2      Group4     Item 41
> ID-2      Group5     Item 51
> ID-2      Group5     Item 52
> ```

Based on the input id, I will get few groups, that has few items in each group inturn. I need a result set that concatenates as below:

Input: ID-1
OutPut in single column:

> ```
> Item 11 - Item 21
> Item 11 - Item 22
> Item 12 - Item 21
> Item 12 - Item 22
> Item 13 - Item 21
> Item 13 - Item 22
> ```

Input: ID-2
OutPut in single column:

> ```
> Item 31 - Item 41 - Item 51
> Item 31 - Item 41 - Item 52
> Item 32 - Item 41 - Item 51
> Item 32 - Item 41 - Item 52
> ```

The output should have all combinations of one item from each group that belongs to the input ID.
Note that the number groups under the ID is not fixed and number of items in a group is not fixed.

Comment: You said that you are writing the code - please let us see what do you have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()` to number your groups and then use this column to communicate in `connect by` clause in hierarchical query:

```
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(column3, ' - '), ' - ') as list 
  from (select dense_rank() over (order by column2) rnk, column1, column2, column3
          from yourtable where column1 = 'ID-1')   
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by prior rnk + 1 = rnk 
  start with rnk = 1
```

Test data and output:

```
create table yourtable (Column1 varchar2(10), Column2 varchar2(10), Column3 varchar2(10));
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-1', 'Group1', 'Item 11');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-1', 'Group1', 'Item 12');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-1', 'Group1', 'Item 13');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-1', 'Group2', 'Item 21');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-1', 'Group2', 'Item 22');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-2', 'Group3', 'Item 31');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-2', 'Group3', 'Item 32');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-2', 'Group4', 'Item 41');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-2', 'Group5', 'Item 51');
insert into yourtable values( 'ID-2', 'Group5', 'Item 52');

LIST
--------------------
Item 11 - Item 21
Item 11 - Item 22
Item 12 - Item 21
Item 12 - Item 22
Item 13 - Item 21
Item 13 - Item 22
```

Comment: This worked almost perfect, but often running into ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long error. Is possible to use XMLAGG or simillar that I can clob? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I think so. But this is a new topic, I suggest that maybe you should ask a new question. Other users may have more knowledge about this or other ideas. I did what I could ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr(B.perm,4,length(B.perm)) from 
(select level l,sys_connect_by_path(A.Column3, ' - ') as perm , sys_connect_by_path(A.Column2, ' - ') ttt
from (select t.* from yourTable t where t.Column1 = 'ID-2')A -- ID-2 is your input
connect by level <= 3 -- 3 is your distinct group count for your input
order by level)B
where B.l = 3 and instr(B.ttt , 'Group3 - Group4 - Group5') > 0 -- 3 is your distinct group count for your input , *** Group3 - Group4 - Group5 is your merged data according to your input
order by substr(B.perm,4,length(B.perm))asc
```

I test it, it works both ID's if you set values correct.